# How to plot matplotlib errorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I tried to plot error bar with Matplotlib like graphic attached, I can't made it, any suggestion?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Media   = data["Media"]
Periodo = data["Periodo"]
P10th     = data["P10th"]
P90th     = data["P90th"]
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups

width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar(Media, P90th, P10th, color='red', ls='--', marker='o', capsize=5, capthick=1, ecolor='black')
plt.xticks(ind, ('1910-1940', '1950-1990', '1990-2000', '2001-2010') )
ax.set_ylim(ylims)
```

[image: I tried to plot with marplotlib this kind of graphic]

[image: here my data], please can you help me.

This is my output

[image]

Comment: I edited my question and put the code that I tried. Thanks

Comment: Do you need the line itself to be red and dotted?

Comment: What is the error / output you currently get? `errorbar` takes up to 4 positional arguments. You called the function as `errorbar(x=Media, y=P90th, xerr=P10th)` and left `yerr` blank (when you don't state the keyword explicity, they get unpacked in default order).

Comment: I don't got error, but basically I can't plot  the percentiles 90 and 10 together.

Comment: In the table you provide, you have 4 data points, while in the plot you have 5. What's the actual data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the plot for your data:

```
p_10 = [.19,.62, .77, 1]
p_90 = [7.19, 6.67, 7.36, 8.25]
M = [1.16, 2.06, 2.17, 2.52]

fig = plt.figure()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = M
yerr = [p_10, # 'down' error
        p_90]  # 'up' error

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, capsize=3, fmt="r--o", ecolor = "black")
```

[image]